# Rolling 6 dice and 4 on the same side

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Guys I made myself a question to answer and its this. What is the probability of having 4 dice land on the same side if I toss 6 dice. I got this answer, I don't know if its correct. I dont want to assume they are fair dice, so:

Let the probability of getting a certain number be P.

Probability of getting exactly 4 same sides is:

10C4 x (P^4) x ((1 - P)^2)

Comment: Do you mean having *exactly* four dice come up the same, or having *at least* four dice come up the same?

Comment: i mean exactly 4 dice come out the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly $4$ out of $6$ dice must be picked out as the dice that
land on the same side. There are $\left({6\atop 4}\right)=15$ possibilities
for that. Then the side on wich these dice land must be picked
out: $6$ possibilities. For the remaining $2$ dice there are $5$
possibillities each to land on: $5\times5=25$ possibilities. This
leads to $15\times6\times25=2250$ possibilities. Totally there are
$6^{6}$ possibilities. So the probability that exactly $4$ land
on the same side is $2250\times6^{-6}$.

Answer (score 0):

It generally goes nPr * p^r * q^ n-r
So in your case
6 P4 * (4/6)^4 * (2/6)^2

Answer (score 0):

The outcome when you roll six die is an ordered 6 tuplet (a,b,c,d,e) , in which each of a,b,c,d,e can take values from 1 to 6. Hence, there are 6^6 possible outcomes in total.

The number of outcomes in which exactly 4 die land on the same side is C(6,4).6.5.5.

Hence, the probability of you getting exactly 4 die on the same face when you roll 6 die is C(6,4).6.5.5/6^6 = 625/7776 (approximately 0.08).